# Detect new outgoing call android

Tags: java, android

I would like my app to detect if a new outgoing call happened

I want to do something like this :

```
if (there was a new outgoing call) {
   do...
} else {
   do...
}
```

Comment: Write your own code, come here only when it doesn't work.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the aim of this website, helping people in computer science ! Your comment is foolish

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Read up on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the android [Broadcast Reciever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). To use it all you have to do is first,

Create a new handler class to handle the broadcast receiver.

```
public class OutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //You can do this to get the phone number, it is only optional
    String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

    //Handle outgoing call event here
    }
}
```

Then register it in the android manifest so it knows where this method is.

```
<receiver android:name=".OutgoingCallReceiver" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
</intent-filter>
```

Finally, create a permission in the android manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
```

And that should do it, hope I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a broadcast receiver to catch the outgoing calls:

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        // your code 
    }
}
```

Then register it in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".CallReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Lastly set the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Detect outgoing phone call event

1)Create OutgoingCallBroadcastReceiver

```
public class OutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(OutgoingCallReceiver.class.getSimpleName(), intent.toString());
    Toast.makeText(context, "Outgoing call catched!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //TODO: Handle outgoing call event here
}

}
```

2. Register OutgoingCallBroadcastReceiver in AndroidManifest.xml
3. Add permission in AndroidManifest.xml